# How can i get just the time value from a UTC DateTime?

Tags: javascript

**I'll walk through the scenario because its confusing:**

I am saving a specific time of day for scheduling purposes in my program (i.e. 3pm).

I have a DateTime recorded in my table in UTC and I only care about the time part (3pm).

Lets say this (3pm) date was created before daylight savings CST.

I am trying to display that time of day on my front end via JavaScript with moment and it converts my time into CST daylight savings time as 2pm.

Is there any possible way to get the time value of a DateTime in UTC to local time without daylight savings logic manipulating it? It was recorded in UTC as 3pm in CST and I just want it to always be 3pm for central time.

Should I be storing static time values like that a different way than DatTime in the DB?

Comment: Using UTC as a future / schedule date could be a bad idea especially if you plan on serving multiple time zones. See [Storing UTC Is Not a Silver Bullet - Jon Skeet](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2019/03/27/storing-utc-is-not-a-silver-bullet/)

Comment: You recommend nodatime instants / storing as long values in the database?